# Django registration 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I have created a website where the user will login with his `email` instead of `username` as Django does. So, I have created an `AUTHENTIFICATION_BACKENDS`:

```
class EmailBackend(object):

   def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
       try:
           user = User.objects.get(email=username)
       except User.MultipleObjectsReturned:
           user = User.objects.filter(email=username).order_by('id').first()
       except User.DoesNotExist:
           return None

       if getattr(user, 'is_active') and user.check_password(password):
           return user
       return None

   def get_user(self, user_id):
       try:
           return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
       except User.DoesNotExist:
           return None
```

My form:

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
   username = forms.CharField()
   email = forms.EmailField()
   age = forms.IntegerField()
   password2 = forms.CharField()
   password = forms.CharField()

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'age', 'email', 'password', 'password2']
```

At this stage, the login with an `email` is Working perfectly. The problem starts when I try to register a user. In registration view:

```
form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
```

register a new user:

```
user = form.save(commit=False)

username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']


user.set_password(password)
user.save()

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

login(request, user)
```

This is where the problem appears. it seems like `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)` is trying to create an anonymous user. What am I doing wrong in my `AUTHENTIFICATION_BACKENDS` ??

Comment: did you include your authentication backend into your project's settings.py

Comment: If you want to authenticate via email, why are you passing a username to the `authenticate` function?

Comment: `AUTHENTIFICATION_BACKENDS` in settings.py is correct.